# Does AWS Kendra have single API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kendra

We are building own javascript and React js application where AWS kendra interface need to be integrated. Does AWS kendra have single API which is used in Javascript or React JS that pulls entire Kendra info into our own application.

Answer (score 3):

Kendra has different APIs per operation (query, index, faq, data source). You can see the list of APIs in [Kendra Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/API_Operations.html)

For reference you can look at [Deploying Kendra Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/deploying.html), there is an example application in reactjs on how to use Kendra search APIs.